# Error when using stsadm.exe to deploy webpart

Tags: deployment, stsadm

I am trying to deploy a webpart to our live SharePoint instance.

```
STSADM.EXE -o AddSolution -filename webpart.wsp
```

I then get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
webpart.wsp: The Solution installation failed.
```

This works fine when used against the the test SharePoint server.

I have double checked all of the permissions that I can think of. Any ideas?

Comment: Any info in the ULS logs ?

Comment: Are you running CMD as an account with farm level permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really could be anything. You will need to look at your log files in order to get more information about what went wrong. These are located in the LOGS folder in the SharePoint root directory. The easiest way of doing this is to use a tool like [ULSViewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) and start it up to capture the logs while you run the stsadm or PowerShell command.

Comment: There was no log being made in the SharePoint log directory, but the error was caught in the Windows Event Viewer. Needed SQL Server access to MSS_Prod_Config in order to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the command as farm administrator, and try temporarily disabling UAC on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you the one that created the web part? Sometimes this can also be a result of the feature trying to reference an object that's not available on the farm (ie: writing to a list that doesn't exist, hard coded list GUID that doesn't match production, etc).

As others have said, check the ULS logs (should confirm the above scenario), ensure you're executing the command logged in as the config admin account, and ensure that the SharePoint Administrator service is running on all of the WFE's.